# Ubuntu 16.04 login screen goes into loop

Tags: loops, authentication, ubuntu-16.04

All of a sudden my ubuntu 16.04 login screen goes into loop. Once I enter the password and login, black screen appears and then it goes to login page. I'm using a dual boot with ubuntu and Windows. 
I tried below steps but no solution.

Chown .Xattribute
Chmod aw+t /tmp
Reconfigure lightdm.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you can't login again after a logout on Gnome (with Xorg in my case) because the session is not properly closed / something hangs. The solution is to make sure no processes for the logged out user remain running, by executing **killall -9 -u $USER** after logging out, for the user that just logged out.

the command I mentioned needs to run after you select to logout from the Gnome System menu. You can run a command after a session has completed by adding it to the **/etc/gdm3/PostSession/Default** file

When the session has completed, gdm attempts to run **/etc/gdm3/PostSession/display**, or **/etc/gdm3/PostSession/Default**"

If you're trying to use this on a Linux distribution other than Ubuntu or Debian, note that the path to the GDM3 PostSession/Default file might be different!

So let's edit this file with Nano command line text editor:

```
$ sudo nano /etc/gdm3/PostSession/Default
```

> you can login to your machine from the command line (after showing the login screen) by pressing
>   **Ctrl** + **Alt** + **F1** and enter the session name and password, so you can apply the steps .

Above the exit 0 add this command:

```
killall -9 -u $USER
```

to something like that

[image]

Now save the file and exit Nano (to save the file using Nano command line text editor press **Ctrl + o**, then Enter; after saving, exit using **Ctrl + x**).

should now be fixed, and you can give it a try by logging out and logging back in (there's no need for a reboot). I tested this to make sure it works quite a few times (and it worked every time)

In case you're aware of a different, better solution, please let me know in the comments section.

Answer (score 0):

I just pressed Alt+F3, then typed my username and the password. After that UI ran the following command 
`sudo startx`
and then my password again and I got in.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem occurred to me so what I did was opened TTL through `ctrl` + `Alt` + `F1` 
Then in the terminal enter hostname and password 
then `cat .xsession-errors` you will find errors 
In my case ,I made some changes on PATH variable file `/etc/environment` so removing my changes helped me

Answer (score -1):

Create new user with <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> 
Give all sudo permission to that user. And then again <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd> and reboot. 
After reboot login with new user .
Enjoy ...!!